# How to create this kind of facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create fb page,and to force users to like page,and to share if they want to see content of my fb fan page.
So,like that page,share that page,and you can than show content of that page.

Comment: That's called a Pyramid Scheme, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "*capture*" if the landing user on your **Page Tab** likes the page or not and if not show them different content and encourage them to *Like* the page to get more!

I've written an in-depth tutorial on [how to check if a user is fan of your Facebook page](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/determine-if-the-user-likes-fan-of-your-page-when-landing-on-your-page-tab/29/) and included a real world examples from a famous Facebook pages!

And just to add to my own article above, another **GREAT** example is one the "*most*" popular pages on Facebook [Coca-Cola](http://www.facebook.com/cocacola?sk=app_288150719365)!

---

Just a side **note**, you don't **force** the users....you **encourage** them!

Answer (score 1):

The closest you could get is to use a Canvas page with a Like Box or something embedded in it. You can listen for the "Like" by waiting for an `FB.event.subscribe(edge.create)` event in embedded Javascript.

I would caution you to abide by the terms for forcing people to like a page.

["Like" Reward Guidelines](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/like_button/)

[Facebook API Policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

Comment: everybody do that? any example,link?

Comment: We're here to help, not do it for you. If you can't use Google, then figure out how to. If you want somebody to do it for you, you can hire a paid programmer to do it all.

Comment: @Blender of course,I try using google and Pyramid Scheme but didnt get to much with that,@ifaour answer help.Tnx @Corey Larson for help.